# Unity Script error CS1061 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'GetAxis'

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

The full error message I am receiving in Unity and I am working on a mac.

Assets/Scripts/Controller.cs(19,45): error CS1061: 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'GetAxis' and no accessible extension method 'GetAxis' accepting a first argument of type 'Vector2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the code I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private Vector2 moveVelocity;
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

void Start() {
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(moveInput.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
}

void fixedUpdate () {
    rigidBody.MovePosition(rigidBody.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
}
```

Please let me know if there is any additional information needed.

Comment: Um, are you really sure you want to create a variable with its constructors containing its own properties and btw https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html doesnt list GetAxis.. I think you were looking for the Input class ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got `Input` and `moveInput` confused. Also, if you have a RigidBody or RigidBody2d you should try and not modify the position of GameObjects directly, instead using the `AddForce` method. I would remove the fixed update method and instead modify your Update method to be the following:

```
void Update() {
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    rigidBody.AddForce(moveInput.normalized * speed);
}
```